# What is the best practice for passing dynamic parameter in WebApi

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameter-passing, webapi

My `Action`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
void Foo(Dictionary<string, object> prm)
{
    var sql = "whatever";
    var sqlPrms = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (prm.TryGetValue("Condition1",out var c1))
    {
        sql += " and Condition1=@c1";
        sqlPrms.Add(new SqlParameter("c1", c1));
    }

    if (prm.TryGetValue("Condition2", out var c2))
    {
        sql += " and Condition2=@c2";
        sqlPrms.Add(new SqlParameter("c2", c2));
    }

    ExecuteSql(sql, sqlPrms);
}
```

The point is **dynamic** conditoins, I can't define a parameter model class, but use `Dictionary` the problem is `Value` can only be `object`, it might cause get incorrect data type when deserialize, what is the better way?

Comment: What are the different objects you’re trying to pass through?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Different actions access different database tables, so there will be different query conditions, `Employee` accept name/sex/department, `Store` accept city/brand..., But I can't define a `EmployeeParameter` class with Name/Sex such properties, because user maybe just query by name, not care sex, I can't write `sex=@xx` in sql always. I don't know if I made it clear.

Comment: No, use a class to do validation etc. & then use the object  values for building your query - just build in logic to not send gender for example if it’s not specified

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Problem is when `null` is also a valid value, Example, ReleaseDate is null means not release yet, users can pass null to query unreleased items.

Comment: This is more regarding logic then - what is the **actual** question?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which contains all the details such as the name and value type, and pass a list/array of that class.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ValueType {get;set;}
    public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then the ValueType is then something like `"String", "Decimal", "MyOtherClass"` etc.
If you only work from narrowly defined types, this could be an enum, but that would make future expansion more complex.